# Java - Libgdx set the cursor to the hand pointer

Tags: java, libgdx, cursor, mouse

I have been doing some research on libgdx and can't find anything relating to this, you can set the pointer image but that isn't what I'm wanting, I tried the set cursor with j frame and stuff but it wouldn't work, what I want is for the default hand cursor to be set when it is called

Comment: Can you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've tried? What exactly do you mean when you say that it wouldn't work?

Comment: I tried using the normal libgdx set cursor method but that sets it to a picture, I want to set it to java cursors.hand cursor and stuff, could I convert that to a pixmap then set it using the libgdx method

Comment: Also, I know I could add my own cursor that looks like the hand but I want a default hand cursor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do that in default LWJGL backend. You may have some luck by using Swing/AWT, embedding libGDX via [LwjglCanvas](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/backends/gdx-backend-lwjgl/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/lwjgl/LwjglCanvas.java) and setting the cursor via Swing. But converting the hand cursor to bitmap and using standard [Gdx.graphics.setCursor()](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Cursor-visibility-%26-catching) will be much easier.

Comment: How am I suppose to convert cursors.hand cursor to a pixmap when it is type int

Comment: You will probably have to draw it yourself, find it on the internet or somehow get it from your system. However beware that last two options may not be possible due to licensing issues.

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want. It displays as a non-pointing hand for me on Ubuntu MATE, but it looks like it points on all versions of Windows. Don't know about macOS. Definitely do as much testing as you can:

```java
Gdx.graphics.setSystemCursor(Cursor.SystemCursor.Hand);
```

Other valid constants are `Arrow` (default cursor), `Ibeam`, `Crosshair`, `HorizontalResize` and `VerticalResize`.

Comment: Thanks man, I appreciate the answer I was looking for, even 5 years later